# ios why UIBarbuttonItem in my navigationBar sometimes disappear but still could response action?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

In my Controller Initialize method 'initWithXXX' I write this for custom leftBarbuttonItem, This Item sometimes disappear but it could still response the action that setting before.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.myleftBarItem;-(UIBarButtonItem *)myleftBarItem{

if (!_myleftBarItem) {
    UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    backButton.frame = CGRectMake(3, 0, 44, 44);
    [backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navi_back"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    backButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -20, 0, 0);
    [backButton setTitle:HXGetStringWithKeyFromTable(@"STR_BACK",nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    backButton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -13, 0, 0);
    backButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];
    [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(goBackToClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    _myleftBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
}
return _leftBarIterm;}
```

Comment: add codes for how you created the button.

Comment: Check your bar button frame using debug hierarchy. Share your both code working one and nonworking also with navigation setup

Comment: @Krunal I have tested it, and the result is same with previous version.but if you use the property of leftBarButtonItems in iOS11 will appear another trouble.